# 2D array: how to print on exact spots

Tags: c, multidimensional-array

can someone help me with accessing elements in 2D array and printing something on that exact spot?

For example, here I enter i & j coordinates,

```
int i,j,A[5][5];

    for(i=0;i<2;i++){
        for(j=0;j<2;j++){    
            scanf("%d",&A[i][j]);
        }
    }
```

And lets say I want to print number 1 on exact spot there i & j meet, and rest spots leave blank

example
[picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AUIvP.gif)

I have an idea on how to do it, but cannot write it in a code. 
My idea was to test every element (number) with each other and when `(if)` two elements which user entered match, `printf("1");`... `else printf(" ");`

And of course after entering elements I would access and print with another nested for loop.

Edit: I wish to do this without using pointers.

Thank you :)

Comment: What are you trying to access? After filling the array you can directly do something like printf("%d", A[0][1])

Comment: I can do that yes, but that would be manually.
I want to achieve to print on exact spots after entering coordinates, they don't have to be [0][1], it was just an example

Comment: So you want to have a random i and j and what is it going to print?

Comment: What I wanted to say was: print any coordinate, it can be [0][1], [2][5], etc

Comment: But in what situation, because you can do that or like a function like this:      void printExactSpot(int i, int j, int A,) { printf("%d", A[i][j]); } Now you can call it like printExactSpot(2,1,A);

Comment: It the goal to print at a specific location on the terminal window or to print from a specific location in the array and just let it print at the next available location on the terminal window?

Comment: My goal is to print a number on spots which user enters
for example user enters
1 4 ...

2 3
in the array

after entering, something, a number should be printed out on those coordinates (1,4), (5,6) and rest of the spots leave blank, oh and there don't have to be 2 coordinates, user can enter n coordinates, 2 was just  to simplify in order to show what I want to accomplish

Comment: You can use the function I wrote above and have that in a while loop and check it until the user doesn't want to enter more coordinates.